# What does "down to the wells" mean?

Tags: meaning

> 'if a man has his private spite laid up against you, the Unions give
>   him his excuse for workin' it off.'
>
> 'Well I know it,'said Hal.
>
> 'They never let you go, them spiteful ones. I knowed a plasterer in
>   Eighteen hundred Sixty-one--C'if a man has his private spite laid up
>   against you, the Unions give him his excuse for workin' it off.'
>
> 'Well I know it,'said Hal.
>
> 'They never let you go, them spiteful ones. I knowed a plasterer in
>   Eighteen hundred Sixty-one--**down to the wells**. He was a Frenchy--a bad
>   enemy he was.'

This is from "[Rewards and Fairies](https://archive.org/details/rewardsfairies00kipl)" The Wrong Thing by Kipling.

I do not understand what "down to the wells" means.

I would be glad if somebody could explain this to me.

Comment: You have omitted a critical component here: "Wells" should be capitalized. It is a place name. The plasterer was from a place called "the Wells." It is usually wiser to provide a link to the source, although in this case, many of the online sources _also_ lack a capital "W." This is because the book is in the public domain (anyone publish it) and over the years Kipling's work has been re-entered and "OCRed" so frequently that many important details (like this captilization) have disappeared and other errors have been introduced.

Comment: It's probably Tunbridge Wells, just thirteen miles from Kipling's home where *Puck of Pook's Hill* and *Rewards and Fairies* are set.

Comment: I would not fault @Hiroshi for the version that he/she posted. It is not his/her fault that many online versions have *wells*. I did, however, downvote this question because it did not include a link to the source. I asked Hiroshi to do this in his last question about this same story. A link should be included every time.

Comment: A working link with *Wells*: [link](https://archive.org/details/rewardsfairies00kipl).

Comment: @AlanCarmack Not a whit of "fault" is ascribed to the OP in my comment! The fault is ascribed clearly to the clowns who make an industry of mangling public domain works.

Comment: @StoneyB ...and [immortalized](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/b5c3ba34-61e0-4096-9b09-2507205daeaf) by Lean and Rains...

Comment: @P.E.Dant What does *down to the Wells* mean here?

Comment: @AlanCarmack It means that in 1861 the speaker knew _un plâtrier Français_ in a place called "the Wells." Do you take a differenrt meaning?

Comment: Thank you for many useful advices and answers. I will make a link to the online text every time. In the book I have(The Centenary Edition 1982), well is not capital---"down to the wells"  Your comments are so helpful for me!! Thwnk you so much again.

Answer (score 3):

In this passage from Rudyard Kipling's 1909 short story *The Wrong Thing,* the speaker in the dialogue tells about a French plasterer whom he knew in 1861 at a location called **the Wells.** This may refer to *Tunbridge Wells,* an English town located near Kipling's own residence.

This usage is redolent of what Kipling perceived as the idiom of a working-class British speaker of his era. In English, we often speak to this day of *going down to London,* and the idiom here is of the same lineage.

**Down to the Wells** here means *at a place called "the Wells."*

Comment: Thank you so much for many advice and answers. I will show the link to the text each time. The book I have (The Centenary edition 1982), well is not capital."down to the well. But the meaning of this sentence is impossible to understand for a foreigner. Thank you so much again!

Comment: I don't doubt this usage. I am unfamiliar with it, and wonder if you have any examples of it from other sources, of anything *down to* meaning *at*.

Comment: I can scare some up. It's cognate with things like "I have a friend over to Brighton."